# How can I make my app to install on SD on Android Studio

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

but I'm wondering how can I make it install directly on SD, because I do not want to spends internal memory on :/

Answer (score 0):

Modify your manifest to include the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

More information can be found in the [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)